# Advice on installing a new SSD/Windows 7 Raid setup

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bios, raid-0

I was wondering if I needed to do anything before setting up my new PC: I will have 2xSSD in RAID 0 (hopefully).

Do I need to configure anything in the BIOS before setting up Windows 7 64-bit? It will be hardware RAID not on the motherboard itself.

Any advice after setting Windows 7 up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is hardware raid from the motherboard raid controller, it will just work. Go ahead and install Windows and life is good.

For super duper perf, get out your checkbook and get a megaraid controller... 
http://www.lsi.com/Pages/default.aspx